# php-mysql not working

Tags: rhel, php, mysql

I'm running on RHEL6. I have installed `php` and `php-mysql`.

`<?php  phpinfo(); ?>` is working perfectly.

But I can't connect to MySQL
is there a way to confirm that `php-mysql` is not working on my server

[EDIT]

I'm trying to connect to a remote database from a webpage
when I open up my webpage it displays 
`Can't connect to MySQL server on 'ipaddress' (110)`

Remote database is working and I can successfully telnet to that ip from my ip and port 3306

Comment: What errors are you getting? What configuration have you done? Did you confirm that your mysql daemon is up and running? Can you connect and use the database with other tools?

Comment: I have only installed php-mysql because my database is on a remote server. I haven't done any configuration changes

Comment: as for the errors, my page displays `Can't connect to MySQL server on 'ipaddress' (110)`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add those details. Also include whether you can connect successfully to that database with other tools from that machine.

Comment: Do you have SE Linux in enforcing mode? Check the logs to see if your policy is blocking db connections. Also, is this running via Apache or fast cgi?

Answer (score 0):

Since you can establish a TCP connection (over telnet), it sounds like the problem that there is not a grant on the remote database server for the user your are using in your code.

On the remote database side, you will want to run a query like the following. This should add the appropriate grants for the account you are using from the IP address you are connecting from.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `database`.* TO 'username'@'cli.ent.ipa.ddr' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: i'm currently using root credentials

Comment: It is possible that the root user only has a grant for localhost (i.e. unix socket), as it is generally not a good idea to use the root credentials for remote connectivity.

If you run the following query, you can double check if there is a grant for the root user that allows remote connectivity:
    SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user;